# What's the difference between LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE and LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

[LoadLibarayExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa)

> Unless an application depends on specific image mapping characteristics, the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE value should be used with either LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE. This allows the loader to choose whether to load the module as an image resource or a data file, selecting whichever option enables the system to share pages more effectively. Resource functions such as FindResource can use either mapping.

There are three similar flags for loading `LoadLibraryEx` to load resource dll.
Both `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE|` (`LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE`) works well with subsequence load res apis like `FindResource`.

So what's the difference between `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` and `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` and how to chose?

Comment: [Loading a DLL as a Data File or Image Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa#loading-a-dll-as-a-data-file-or-image-resource) explains the differences. It also explains which one to use: *"Unless an application depends on specific image mapping characteristics, the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` value should be used with either `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`."*

Comment: *When the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE value is used, the module is loaded as an image using portable executable (PE) section alignment expansion.* - this is main difference

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` was added in Vista. XP/2003 and earlier only had `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`. If all you are doing is accessing resources with functions such as `FindResource`, `Load­Resource`, and `Enum­Resource­Types`, `Load­String`, and `Format­Message`, etc, then you don't *need* to use  `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, just plain `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` by itself will still work, just as it did in XP/2003 and below. That said, Microsoft's [internationalisation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/loading-a-win32-pe-resource-module) recommends using `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, so it is possible some post-XP/2003 features (such as MUI strings) may not work correctly without it.

What are circumstances in which you might **need** to use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`? [Firefox bug 1702086 comment 20](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1702086#c20) mentions an example of a scenario in which `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` can be required:

> The second part is to add `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` along with
> `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` to the call to `LoadLibraryEx`. This is needed
> to read information from the sections outside the PE headers because
> RVA (= relative virtual address) is an address after relocation.
> Without `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, a module is mapped without relocation, so `GetPdbInfo()` accesses wrong memory resulting in a crash.

Normally, when Windows maps a DLL or EXE into memory, it doesn't set up a simple one-to-one correspondence between memory addresses and file offsets: there can be gaps between the sections of the image file (inter-section padding; this is what the "portable executable (PE) section alignment expansion" mentioned in the documentation is about), zero-initialised sections, etc. If you use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, Windows loads the image file into memory in the same way as it does for executable images, so the sections in memory will be at the same offset from the image as if the DLL/EXE was being loaded to execute. By contrast, if you just pass `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` without `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, it maps the image file into memory contiguously. This means memory addresses–whether absolute virtual addresses (VAs) or addresses relative to the image base (RVAs)–will be incorrect, and if you try to access the data at them, you will end up reading from the wrong memory address, which is likely to cause a crash.

This Firefox bug concerns Firefox's crash reporting system, and part of it needs to read debugging data out of image files. Without `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`, the debug data is not loaded at the expected memory address, and trying to access it can cause a crash.

How then is it that `FindResource`/etc still (mostly?) work without `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`? Since they date back to XP/2003 and earlier when only `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` existed, they are written to take into account the differences in memory layout between image files and data files. You could do the same thing (by reading the section headers and applying fixups to addresses based on them)–or you could just load the image with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` and not have to worry about that.